# sending emails to different mail address according to different detail of the form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

> I want to send the data of this form as emails to different mail
>   address according to the different cities; eg: details of person
>   select "gampaha"to email1@mail.com and details of person select
>   colombo to email2@mail.com etc...please help me.

```
<form action="">
        <ul>
            <li><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="type name" /></li>
            <li><input name="email" type="email"  placeholder="type email"/></li>
            <li><input name="num" type="number" placeholder="type contact number" /></li>
           <select name="city">
                <option value="gampaha">gampaha</option>
                <option value="colombo">colombo</option>
                <option value="ragama">ragama</option>
                <option value="jaffna">jaffna</option>
           </select>
            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" /></li>
        </ul>

    </form>
```

Comment: you would just need a PHP side, hash map of options to emails, and then use the MAIL() call.

Comment: Where is your PHP code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Show what you have tried. Do you have any php side to this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$to` would be the recipient email address:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 switch($_POST['city']) {
  case 'gampaha': $to = 'to1@gmail.com'; break;
  case 'colombo': $to = 'to2@hotmail.com'; break;
 }
}
```

Next time, please show the code you've already tried. Rather than relying on others to do the work for you, try something yourself. If it doesn't work, try again. If that doesn't work, post your code and ask where it's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried but I couldn't even compleate the function.Next time I try more harder,I got your advice .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:

```
#assuming you are POSTing
# use a DB or have some static references to the options.
$choices["gampaha"] = "mail1@mail.net";
$choices["colombo"] = "mail2@mail.net";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$to = $choices[$_POST["city"]];
$r = mail($to, "email request", $_POST['name']." ".$_POST["email"]." ".$_POST["num"]);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

- You will want to make sure that everything isset or is " the empty string",
- you will want to build a real email.
- you will want to verify that the email is correct (client side and server side)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to show you one more `logic` :

```
<?php
$arr_city_email = array(
    "gampaha" => "email1@gmail.com",
    "colombo" => "email2@gmail.com"
);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $to = $arr_city_email[$city];
}
?>
```